# PYTHON Change value in json object based on list of keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

Say we have a json dict `our_dict = {'foo': { 'key': 'value' }, 'fizz': 'buzz'}`

Find function `f(d, l_keys, value)` that changes the value in `d` indexed by the list of keys `l_keys` and returns `d`. The length of the list could be varying, error handling is not required.

Example:

`f(out_dict, ['foo', 'key'], 'a new value')`

should return

`{'foo': { 'key': 'a new value' }, 'fizz': 'buzz'}`

My attempt so far:

```
_tmp = d[l_keys[0]]
for i in range(1, len(l_keys)):
    _tmp = _tmp[l_keys[i]]
_tmp = value
```

The problem is that changes to _tmp are not reflected in d

Comment: Post your attempt as well please

Comment: A json dict doesn't exists. JSON is a STRING content. Then what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Can I add my attempt in the comments?

Comment: Edit your question and add it there @SuperMan

Comment: [edit] the post to add any thing important to the post

Comment: Fixed it! Poggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is a string format, there is no such JSON dict, becaues dict is a python structure. `our_dict = {'foo': { 'key': 'value' }, 'fizz': 'buzz'}` is only a python dict

---

I'd suggest you iterate on the param keys except the last, to read the interesting inner dict, then do the replacement

```
def f(our_dict: dict, param: list[str], param1: str):
    tmp_dict = our_dict
    for p in param[:-1]:
        tmp_dict = tmp_dict[p]
    tmp_dict[param[-1]] = param1
    return our_dict
```

Examples

```
our_dict = {'foo': {'key': 'value'}, 'fizz': 'buzz'}
print(f(our_dict, ['foo', 'key'], 'a new value'))
# {'foo': {'key': 'a new value'}, 'fizz': 'buzz'}

our_dict = {'foo': {'key': {'a': {'b': 'value'}}}, 'fizz': 'buzz'}
print(f(our_dict, ['foo', 'key'], 'a new value'))
# {'foo': {'key': 'a new value'}, 'fizz': 'buzz'}

our_dict = {'foo': {'key': {'a': {'b': 'value'}}}, 'fizz': 'buzz'}
print(f(our_dict, ['foo', 'key', 'a', 'b'], 'a new value'))
# {'foo': {'key': {'a': {'b': 'a new value'}}}, 'fizz': 'buzz'}
```